# How to convert a tag to "..."

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of links.

Respectively, following them will display. When the text is large. Link into two lines are.

i do not don't want a text wrap.

like :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" > Link within two lines </a>
```

[Link  within 

 two lines](http://test.com)

convert to :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" > Link within two lines </a>
```

[Link within ...](http://test.com)

Is it possible?

I have no idea

Comment: Take a look at `white-space` in CSS as well as `text-overflow`.

Comment: @Jasper or maybe `text-overflow:ellipsis`, but neither of those are javascript/html (tagged)

Comment: give them a width and use `text-overflow: ellipsis` in your CSS. If you really want to do javascript you can but its way harder. You have to get the innerHTML parse the string for the length then add the "..."

Comment: @Brian True about the tag, I'd still suggest using CSS though. Browser support is great: http://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing here is the `text-overflow:ellipsis;` overflow property.

Now whenever a new line is made, it means the text doesn't fit on the first line anymore. However *we don't want a second* line so we use `white-space: nowrap;`.

To determ the overflow we use `overflow: hidden;` where we use a block display so we can give the anchor a custom width. `display: inline-block;` in this case, as i want it to have to with of the content. Where we give the custom width, when we overflow `width: 90px;`.

 So we get:

```
a 
{
    width: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Where as a text inside the 90px has no [...] tag.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9TUX/)

Answer (score 1):

You need a block element and a width so you can overflow.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
style="display:block; width:30px;text-overflow:ellipsis"> Link within two lines </a>
```